# "Category laws" in Haskell wiki

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

According to Haskell wiki,

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Category_laws

> **Category laws**
> There are three laws that categories need to follow. Firstly, and most simply, the composition of morphisms needs to be associative.

However,

**Composition of relations is associative**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Properties

**the composition of functions is always associative**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Properties

So, in what scenario, Haskell community (or ones who wiki suppose) consider that the composition of morphisms is not associative breaking the rule?

Thanks.

Comment: That's just the mathematical definition of a category. As it applies to Haskell, with the "Hask" category, then as you point out, the law is satisfied, since function composition is always associative. But the point needs to be made in order to show that Hask really is a category.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Well, no, it's not a definition or **laws that categories need to follow** but simply a property automatically emerges. Which provides a very wrong information to learners.

Comment: Just to make sure, this is a question to confirm if there are any special situation in programming in Haskell so that the wiki claims the "law", or simply misconception.

Comment: it is simply giving the *mathematical definition of a category*, as can be found in any introduction to category theory - most of them totally unrelated to Haskell. See eg the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)#Definition) which states exactly the same laws. This definition is surely highly relevant - indeed essential - in any formal or semi-formal description of what category theory is.

Comment: @RobinZigmond "such that the following axioms hold:" does not mean **laws that categories need to follow**.

Comment: Um, it does. "axioms" and "laws" are synonyms in this context. If you construct a "category" which doesn't follow those laws, then - by definition - it isn't actually a category.

Comment: You don't understand.  "such that the following axioms hold:" is a statement that axitoms are "automatically hold", which is not a requirement.  Again, it does not mean laws that categories need to follow.  and why you so much want to advocate the false statement in the wiki?? What is your motivattion?

Comment: I am not "advocating" for any "false statements", merely trying to explain that the wikibook is giving the standard, and correct, definition of a category as can be found in any textbook or introduction to the subject. No-one is saying that the laws "automatically hold" - they do not, and it is easy to give examples (as @danidiaz has done in his answer) where they do not. Perhaps you were confused by the word "axiom"? In some contexts this does indeed mean statements which are assumed to "automatically hold", but that's not the case here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220785/discussion-between-robin-zigmond-and-smooth-writing).

Comment: No, sorry, I don't want to.  
**the composition of functions is always associative.** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Properties , If you feel "the composition of morphisms needs to be associative."  is logically valid from the statement "such that the following axioms hold:" category wikipedia, I will edit because it is also potentially wrong statement.

Comment: Fine, but it's just a courtesy to others to avoid spamming the comments. Yes, function composition is always associative. But (and perhaps this is what you are overlooking?) there is nothing in the definition of a category that forces morphisms to be functions, or "composition" to mean literal function composition. It's actually very easy to define something which meets the definition of a category, except that the "composition" fails to be associative. So that law is necessary.

Comment: **Composition of relations is associative.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations#Properties

"It's actually very easy to define something which meets the definition of a category, except that the "composition" fails to be associative" What is that?

Comment: Again, that's a very specific example of one operation, that happens to be associative. But it can't possibly apply to any possible category, because nothing forces that definition of "composition" to be the one used in the category. As for an example that fails to satisfy the associative law, @danidiaz has already given one in his answer. I could easily give others, but they won't fit in a comment and another answer for this would be imo superfluous m

Comment: @RobinZigmond My apology and appreciation, it turns out you have been absolutely right, and I've been wrong. I also found https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/database+of+categories and now finally the varieties of categories directly corresponds to varieties of morphism. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly identify function composition and relation composition as associative operations, and then appear to ask this question:

> Since all the operations that we call composition are already proven to be associative, why do we make associativity a requirement of composition operations?

There are two subtle bugs in this question.

1. You assume that the collection of operations that we call composition only contains function and relation composition. But this is not so: I think I could, given time, write down 20-30 different *classes* of composition operations, with each class containing an infinite number of actual composition operations!
2. Your assumed causal relation is backwards. We do not start by calling a bunch of different things composition, and then deciding to demand that they be associative; rather, first we identify some conditions that we like (associativity, having an identity, being well-typed) and then allow ourselves to attach the label "composition" to *any* operation that fulfills those conditions.

Let's do some examples, in the style of point (2). We will first build up a mathematical structure of interest to us, then we will ask: can we call this a category if we want to?

**Sets with function composition**

Suppose I proposed the following mathematical structure:

- There is a big collection of objects, one for each set that's possible. (This statement can't be formulated in set theory! But that's okay. We don't *have* to work in set theory if we don't want to.)
- There is a collection of arrows for each pair of objects; namely, for sets X and Y, there is one arrow of type X -> Y for each function whose domain is X and whose codomain is Y.
- To compose two arrows, we use standard function composition from set theory.

Is this structure a category? As you correctly observed in your question, the answer is *yes*, because:

1. For any object X, we can create an arrow of type X -> X for which composing with other arrows does nothing (namely, the function that returns its input unchanged).
2. As you correctly observed, we can prove that function composition is associative.

**Numbers with addition**

Here is a somewhat simpler structure:

- There is a single object, named X.
- There is a collection of arrows of type X -> X; in this collection is one arrow for each natural number.
- To compose the arrows representing numbers m and n, produce the arrow representing the number m+n.

Notice that in this structure, the composition operation we have defined is *neither* function composition nor relation composition! The question we are asking now is: are we lying to ourselves when we attach the label composition to this operation, or is that a sensible thing to call it?

In this case, the answer is *yes*, we can call it composition (and call the whole structure a category), because:

1. We can create an arrow of type X -> X for which composing with other arrows does nothing (namely, the arrow representing the number 0).
2. As we all know, addition is associative.

**Positive numbers with addition**

How about this slight modification to the previous example:

- There is a single object, named X.
- There is a collection of arrows of type X -> X; in this collection is one arrow for each positive natural number.
- To compose the arrows representing numbers m and n, produce the arrow representing the number m+n.

Can I call this a category? Is this relation something to which I can attach the label "composition"? (Note that the operation itself is *the same operation* as before!) In this case, the answer is ***no***, we should not call this structure a category, and we should not call this operation a composition, because although the operation is associative, there is no arrow which leaves other arrows unchanged when composing with them.

**Numbers with weird exponentiation**

One more structure:

- There is a single object, named X.
- There is a collection of arrows of type X -> X; in this collection is one arrow for each natural number.
- To compose arrows m and n:

  - If either of m or n is 0, return the other. For example, the composition of 0 and 1 is 1; the composition of 2 and 0 is 2; and the composition of 0 and 0 is 0.
  - Otherwise, take the exponentiation m^n.

Can we call this structure a category? Is the final operation something we could label as a "composition"? In this case, the answer is ***no***, because although there is an arrow which leaves the others alone under composition (namely 0), the purported composition operation is not associative:

```
2^(1^2) = 2^1 = 2
(2^1)^2 = 2^2 = 4
```

With some work, we can cook up fancier examples that fail the category laws in even subtler ways (for example, by being associative, but only having one-sided identities). But by now I hope the pattern is clear: the category laws are desiderata that we use, and the decision we make in each case is about whether a mathematical structure we are interested in is something we can call a "category". (Of course, we are still allowed to be interested in it and study it even if the answer to that question is no!)

Comment: Thank you very much. I also found https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/database+of+categories and now finally the varieties of categories directly corresponds to varieties of morphism. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a datatype/operation combination that is not a valid `Category` instance.

The datatype consists simply in a function annotated with some `Int` value:

```
import Prelude
import qualified Control.Category as C

data Subs a b = Subs Int (a -> b)
```

And here's the bogus `Category` instance. The composition performs subtraction of the annotations:

```
instance C.Category Subs where
    id = Subs 0 Prelude.id
    (Subs x f) . (Subs y g) = Subs (y - x) (f . g)
```

However, because [subtraction is not associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property#Non-associative_operation), that instance is not valid!

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let Subs u _ = (Subs 3 id) C.. ((Subs 10 id) C.. (Subs 2 id))
        Subs v _ = ((Subs 3 id) C.. (Subs 10 id)) C.. (Subs 2 id)
    print u
    print v
```

This returns

```
-11
-5
```

showing that the order of composition matters, contrary to the `Category` laws.

Comment: So, the library is broken, because **the composition of functions is always associative.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Properties

Can you do the same thing without using the library because what you did in the code is not a function composition.

Comment: @smooth_writing Function composition is how "Category" composition is implemented for the function type constructor (->). But things other than functions can have Category instances, and they might use operations different from function composition to implement the "Category" composition. These operations should still be associative, however.

Comment: Saying "the library is broken" about a widely used core Haskell library does not do your case any good. But I will try to give the benefit of the doubt and repeat what I've already said: nothing in the mathematical definition of a category forces the "morphisms" to be functions or the "composition" between them to be "actual" composition. These were of course the motivating and most common examples of mathematical categories, but the concept is far richer than that.

Comment: @danidiaz Well, yes, there is also binary relation and composition, and that is also associative.  Just make sure, do you use a word "composition'  as general binary operation? I think everyone agree binary operation of subtraction is not associative, but "binary operation" is generally not "composition".

Comment: @danidiaz For instance, you cannot construct a diagram of composition with the binary operation of subtraction. Again the false statement is "the composition of morphisms needs to be associative." Where is your "composition" from the first place?

Comment: @smooth_writing "the composition of morphisms needs to be associative" is false if you mean "the Haskell type system will automatically ensure that the operation the programmer specifies as Categorical composition is associative, the program will fail to compile otherwise, for example if we use substraction". Haskell's type system is not powerful enough to ensure that. It's the programmer's responsibility to use operations that are actually associative. That doesn't mean the library is broken, it just means that programmers should be careful to respect the expected contract.

Comment: @RobinZigmond  >danidiaz has already given one in his answer. I could easily give others<  As I mentioned above, you cannot provide "composition" at all. This answer merely proposed a binary operation of subtraction which is not called as composition. The statement of the problem is "the composition of morphisms needs to be associative." not "the binary operation needs to be associative."

Comment: @danidiaz I'm not talking about type-system, but that you never provide "composition". What you provide is binary operation of subtraction which is not considered as "composition"  in mathematics.

Comment: "composition" in the context of defining a category does indeed mean an arbitrary operation - but one which satisfies the necessary conditions. Associativity is one of those. It is not the case that the opera must be composition in the sense we understand that from functions - nor that the morphisms necessarily be functions in the first place. Indeed, if you use @danidiaz's example but with adding the numbers instead of subtracting, you have a perfectly valid category in which the morphisms are not functions!

Comment: @danidiaz What you've proved is merely to show a binary operation of subtraction is not associative using the Haskell library. Which is nothing to do with a false statement "the composition of morphisms needs to be associative" because what you provide is not composition in any mathematical sense.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'v never heard of "composition" require a condition "associative" in category theory. Is this your original? Accoding to https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category#OneCollectionOfMorphisms  for every pair of morphisms f and g, where t(f)=s(g), a morphism g∘f, called their composite (also written gf or sometimes f;g

Comment: and **such that the following properties are satisfied:** which means not requirement but 
reduction,

Comment: It's right there in the section you linked to: `such that the following properties are satisfied`. The third bullet point down from that is `composition is associative`. As I already said, this is the basic definition of a category, as you will find in any introduction to the subject - so I have no idea why you are, quite erroneously, singling out the Haskell wikibook for its allegedly "false" (but actually quite correct) statement.

Comment: @RobinZigmond and **such that the following properties are satisfied:** which means not requirement but 
reduction,

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "not requirement but reduction". Those things *are* requirements - if you bring me something that purports to be a category but fails one of those requirements, then it simply isn't a category - by definition. I am sorry but I am not going to respond to you any more because I have spent quite long enough and these comments will not be useful for most people, you seem to be missing something quite fundamental but I am still not sure what, however it would help your cause if you were more humble about what you don't know rather than accusing others of being wrong.